# How to share the useState from one component to all other component and display the same value using react js?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component which shows a text using useState() and the data gets updated in store as well, I want the same text to be present in all the other pages/ components that I have.
Please provide some concepts or examples for implementation.
Note : Using only stateless components.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `React Context` feature.

[React Hooks Sample](https://github.com/ali-master/react-typescript-hooks-sample)

Comment: If my answer helps you, Mark the Answer as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use these values in many components use sessionSotrage, which provides you load the info from other components, another way its use the hook UseContext, the last idea, will be if the component that you will use is a child component you can pass the value as a prop.